# Encrypting a mysql database

Tags: encryption, mysql

I have a MYSQL database (which in itself contains encrypted data MD5 password fields) that I wish to backup and encrypt. The application is PHP on a standard Dreamweaver shared hosted server.

I'm expecting to have to DUMP the entire MYSQL database then encrypt it somehow.

I understand that I will need to shell_exec() a MYSQLdump, then encrypt it with some form of encryption utility.

Can I please have the PHP code to perform this dump/compression/encryption?

If I'm on the right track, I would expect something like:

```
<?php 
1. [connect to database]
2. [perform MYSQLdump]
3. [perform encryption]
4. [write to file: /directory/backup.<timedatestamp>.gz]
5. [create whiskey & celebrate]
?>
```

As a very low-level PHP developer, I need specific functioning code that I can copy/paste if you don't mind please. I'm fine with Steps 1 & 5 but require hand-holding on steps 3,4 & 5.

If PHP does not have any inbuilt encryption and a third-party utility is required, I will need to know how to establish if it is installed on my server and how to install if it is not.

P.S. Products created in 5. willingly shared.

Comment: You'll get a lot further on this site (or anywhere in life for that matter) if you talk about what you've tried to do to complete this task, instead of giving people a recipe to do your job. If you'd like me to do your job, my email is in my profile and my rate is $250/hr.

Comment: i'll do it for $100 an hour but you have to wait for the weekend

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: OK Guys - sorry to cause you offense. I actually researched encryption on Google for an hour viewed multiple sites, including as many answers here as I could regarding encryption. I guess some of us have less programming capability than others eh?